# How to prevent generation of JAXB sources for each maven build?

Tags: maven-2, jaxb, xsd

I use org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 plugin to generate sources from XSD schema. Sources are generated for each build also when schemas are not changed. This seriously slow down build. How can I prevent this behavior and generate sources automatically only if it is really necessary?

My current plugin configuration:

```
<execution>
    <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>jaxb/foo/*.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc/META-INF/jaxb-foo.episode</episodeFile>                           
            <generatePackage>com.foo</generatePackage>
    </configuration>
    <id>jaxb-generate-foo</id>
</execution>
```

Comment: Can you write which jaxb-plugin do you use, cause there are different jaxb plugins.

Comment: org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin version 0.8.3